# iOS7 - UITabBar - Transparent doesn’t work

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview, uitabbar, uiedgeinsets

I m using custom `UITabBar` in my app and i set the translucency to `NO`:

```
if ([self.tabBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setTranslucent:)])
    [self.tabBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

I have `UIViewController` with this `.xib`:

[image]

In the white area i have a `UIScrollView` with `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 70, 0)` as u can see.

My problem is that the `UIViewController` doesn't shrink because of the `UITabBar`, and the UIEdgeInsets is 70 points but starting from the point 480, rather then 410 (480-70).

I want that the 70 points will start from the highest `UITabBar` point (`UITabBar` high is 49 points), point 480-49 = 431.

Any help will be great!

Comment: try self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
it will not let the view scroll behind your tabBar